# How to get ios OneDrive framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

i want to apply OneDrive SDK in my app.

https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-ios

this site has only one way using cocoapod. but i want to apply .framework file(not use cocoapod).

how to get OneDrive.framework file.

@Dylan S

thank you your description, but i have error.

here is my process.

1. download OneDrive source
   [image]
2. in OneDriveSDK folder :  pod install
   [image]
3. and result

[image]

4. open OneDriveSDK.xcworkspace file and build

[image]

5. get OneDriveSDK.framework
   [image]
6. add this framework in my project and buld.
   but i have linking error.

my test code:

```
#import <OneDriveSDK/OneDriveSDK.h>
[ODClient clientWithCompletion:^(ODClient *client, NSError *error){
    if (!error){
//            self.odClient = client;
    }
}];
```

linking error :

[image]

is it right my process?

Comment: You could download the source, configure an Xcode scheme, and build it into a framework.

Comment: @DylanS please let me know in detail. What does it mean? ''configure an Xcode scheme"

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own copy of the framework, without installing it as a Cocoapod but you will still need to use Cocoapods when building. OneDriveSDK uses Cocoapods.

Anyway, start by downloading the code (at master or whatever release you want). It's up on GitHub, so pop on over there. I'll wait.

Next up - install its Cocoapod dependencies so Xcode will be able to build the code. If you don't have Cocoapods installed, you'll need to install the gem with `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Checkout [their guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) for more info.

You install the pods to the project with `pod install` from within the `OndeDriveSDK` directory - it's the one with the file named `Podfile`.

Now you're ready to build: open "OneDriveSDK.xcworkspace" (notice xcworkspace and not xcodeproj).

[image: Xcode scheme setup]

Pick the "OneDriveSDK" scheme and build for "Generic iOS Device". Reference the above screenshot.

Finally, build it. Product -> Build For -> Running. It should just work, it did for me.

Once Xcode finishes, open the "Products" folder. Find "OneDriveSDK.framework" and right-click selected "Show in finder". There's a screenshot below of what to look for. Grab the framework file and you're ready to go. Drop it into your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
sample code: https://github.com/soheilbm/StackOverFlowQ1

---

1. Install cococapod and [Rome plugin](https://github.com/neonichu/Rome)

   ```
   gem install cocoapods
   gem install cocoapods-rome
   ```
2. Create a empty project (Testing) and setup podfile with:

   ```
   platform :ios, '8.0'
   use_frameworks!

   target 'Testing' do
      plugin 'cocoapods-rome'
      pod 'OneDriveSDK'   
   end
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   pod install
   ```
4. Go to Rome directory and copy all frameworks (except **Pods_Testing.framework**)

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help :)